# Taking picture from QGIS Plugin using PyQt

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, pyqt

I have a button in a Plugin to take a photo and relate it with a feature of a layer in QGIS.

My aim is to select a feature, open a camera view (viewfinder), take a photo and save it with the feature id and datetime as file name (e.g. *20210412-112351_22325.jpg*).

To do that I use the code below [based on this post](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/creating-a-camera-application-using-pyqt5/).

The problem is when I use this Plugin in my laptop the picture taken is 1280x720 but with a Surface Book 3 the result picture is 640x320.

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import *
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import *
from qgis.core import (QgsProject,
                       Qgis,
                       QgsExpressionContextUtils)
from qgis.utils import iface

import os
import time

class creaventana(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 1280, 720)
        self.setStyleSheet("background : lightgrey;")
        self.available_cameras = QCameraInfo.availableCameras()
        
        if not self.available_cameras:
            iface.messageBar().pushMessage('No hay cámaras', 'El dispositivo no tiene ninguna cámara',
                                           level=Qgis.Warning,
                                           duration=5)

        self.status = QStatusBar()
        self.status.setStyleSheet("background : white;")
        self.setStatusBar(self.status)
        self.viewfinder = QCameraViewfinder()
        self.viewfinder.show()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.viewfinder)
        self.select_camera(0)
        toolbar = QToolBar("Cámara")
        self.addToolBar(toolbar)
        click_action = QAction("Hacer foto", self)
        click_action.setStatusTip("Esto hace la foto")
        click_action.setToolTip("Hacer foto")
        click_action.triggered.connect(self.click_photo)
        toolbar.addAction(click_action)
        camera_selector = QComboBox()
        camera_selector.setStatusTip("Cámara frontal / trasera")
        camera_selector.setToolTip("Elegir cámara")
        camera_selector.setToolTipDuration(2500)
        camera_selector.addItems([camera.description()
                                  for camera in self.available_cameras])
        camera_selector.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.select_camera)
        toolbar.addWidget(camera_selector)
        toolbar.setStyleSheet("background : white;")
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt5 Cam")

    def select_camera(self, i):
        self.camera = QCamera(self.available_cameras[i])
        self.camera.setViewfinder(self.viewfinder)
        self.camera.setCaptureMode(QCamera.CaptureStillImage)
        self.camera.error.connect(lambda: self.alert(self.camera.errorString()))
        self.camera.start()
        self.capture = QCameraImageCapture(self.camera)
        self.capture.error.connect(lambda error_msg, error,
                                          msg: self.alert(msg))
        self.capture.imageCaptured.connect(lambda d, i: self.status.showMessage("Imagen tomada: " + str(self.save_seq)))
        self.current_camera_name = self.available_cameras[i].description()

        self.save_seq = 0

    def click_photo(self):
        individuos = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Individuos')[0]
        individuoSeleccionado = individuos.selectedFeatures()

        for individuo in individuoSeleccionado:
            idind = individuo['id_ind']

        timestamp = time.strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S')
        ruta = 'D:/fotos/'

        self.capture.capture(os.path.join(ruta, "%s_%s.jpg" % (idind, timestamp)))
        self.save_seq += 1

    def alert(self, msg):
        error = QErrorMessage(self)
        error.showMessage(msg)

def abrecamara(self):
    individuos = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Individuos')[0]
    individuoSeleccionado = individuos.selectedFeatures()
    cuentaIndividuoSeleccionado = len(list(individuoSeleccionado))

    if cuentaIndividuoSeleccionado == 1:
        ventana = creaventana()
        ventana.show()
    elif cuentaIndividuoSeleccionado > 1:
        iface.messageBar().pushMessage('Selección', 'Solo puede haber un individuo seleccionado',
                                       level=Qgis.Warning,
                                       duration=5)
    elif cuentaIndividuoSeleccionado == 0:
        iface.messageBar().pushMessage('Selección', 'Tiene que haber al menos un individuo seleccionado',
                                       level=Qgis.Warning,
                                       duration=5)
```

Comment: I voted to close this post because I think it's more related to PyQt5 and the hardware (laptop / Surface and cameras types) / software (OS, Python, PyQt5 versions) than strictly GIS even if it's used inside QGIS. More a question for StackOverflow.